# What is the GUI frame work used is website with excellent GUI like twitter, www.groupon.com etc

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

I am a java developer, but I am new for GUI development and I wanted to know how to develop such visually appealing yet user friendly GUI

I have started exploring google GWT because developing GUI from scratch with pure HTML will be a big task, I have to make a website for which I need some GUI framwork related to java(like google GWT which have ready to use components)

Its a big website so I need to finalize on the GUI technology, any advice would be really helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a couple of things you should consider when you choose your framework.

1. Consider what are your requirements.
2. The time you have
3. The existing comfort zone and skillset of your developers

For a lot of requirements an combination of AJAX + jQuery + jQUery UI (http://jqueryui.com/) can work wonders.

Comment: +1 for JQuery UI, significantly reduces UI dev time, plus simple.

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome Sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae) extension for google chrome would help you out